# PHP- Queried results to new database

Tags: php, mysql

The code bellow is used to find a client by entering that client's specific username and password. But i want to save the result from any query to specific table called orders. The problem is that i have trouble with coding that. Here is my code and in the loop which the comment "//save the queried results to new database" is, i want to insert the code for the variables which then will be inserted to the table.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "hidden", "hidden") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $min_length = 3;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') AND (`password` LIKE '%".$password."%')") or die(mysql_error());



        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

                //save the queried results to new database
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "Nema rezultati za takov korisnik";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimalnata dolzina na stringot e: ".$min_length;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: U want to insert username and password in order table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: `$query` seems very insecure (based on the name, maybe that is just a bad variable name though). Why not escape `$password` as well? Have you tried writing your `insert` yet? `htmlspecialchars` is the inverse of what you'd want. You want to decode from browser to data source (probably unless you encoded and database...but decoded for browser?).

Comment: @devpro , no i want to insert the name, the city and the address of the queried username

Answer (score 2):

You code has a lot of security issues.

First, you should not pass parameters like username and password **as GET** 
parameters. The browser might save the url in history, a user might share the link to twitter. Not safe, pass parameters with POST.

Second, applying mysql_real_escape_string() to username **will not protect you from an SQL injection**, (see this [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)). **Use prepared statements please**.
You should not use `htmlspecialchars()`, you are not echoing the username to the page. Moreover, you should search the database with the html special characters but not with their html values.

eg, if username = "<username>", search the database with "<username>" and not with "&lt ;username&gt ;". You should only apply `htmlspecialchars` when you echo the username to the page, eg 
`echo 'Hello '.htmlspecialchars($username).', how are you?';`

Third, you use mysql_*, you shouldn't. mysql_* **is deprecated** in PHP 5.5.0 **and removed** in PHP 7. Use mysqli_* instead.

Fourth, you should never, query the database with `password LIKE %$passwordFromuser%`. Imagine you have the password of "hellomypassword" and the username of "Bob". So I login with the credentials:
username = "Bob"
password = "a", so the expression "%a%" matches "hellomypassword". 
So i have accessed your account. 
Same with username, applying '%' to the username is wrong.

Last but not least, **use a strong hashing algorithm** for storing the passwords to the database.

---

Now, the first query should return only one single row (only one row should have a specific set of username and password) so you do not need the
`while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){}`. Just fetch the results once.

Then use the results and perform an INSERT query to the table like the following
`INSERT INTO tbName (rowName1,rowName2) VALUES (rowValue1, rowValue2)`.

Comment: In addition: try password verification using PHP's `password_verify()` and `password_hash()` functions [see: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php]. These use safer encryption methods. So you would get the user's row from the DB, and then check the submitted password against the password column with `password_verify()`. On creation of the user you store the string that `password_hash()` produces with the chosen password.